Entry front door transom
Help! Is it possible to get rid of this transom so I can have a regular door lol. The whole piece has to come out because there is some water damage under it. We can't find a similar door for less than $8K. What clever options does anyone have?
door pic imgur

It isn't clear from your description what is actually damaged, and how badly. Repair is probably an alternative to replacement, but may require hiring someone who has the proper skills.

Yes sorry I added more pics! Water leaked in the house and so the subfloor has some rot under the door.

That should be fixable without losing the expensive and attractive door treatment.
